# Як назвати комплекс з догляду та предмет, призначений для догляду?

Tags: прикметники, словотворення

Який прикметник буде доречний для позначення компексу та/чи предмету для догляду?

Чи буде коректним вживати один і той самий прикметник для позначення косметичних та медичних засобів?

Яке вживання слів *доглядовий* та *доглядальний* є коректним?

"*Доглядальна* косметика", "*доглядова*" чи тільки й виключно "*для догляду*"?

Comment: Якщо момент *вирішальний*, бо він призначений для того, щоб щось вирішити, то косметика може бути *доглядальною*, бо призначена для догляду.

Answer (score 2):

Не можу натішитись цією статтею: [Процесові прикметники в науковій мові](https://r2u.org.ua/node/162), як же ж часто вона стає в нагоді.

Тут ми маємо справу з активною здатністю і з призначенністю для певної дії/функції, отже підійде пункт два.

> **2.**  Прикметники, що вказують на *призначення* виконувати дію чи *здатність/властивість* виконувати дію (*активну* здатність) згідно з настановами вже згаданих репресивних бюлетенів зазнали подвійного тиску. З одного боку, їх інтенсивно заміняли активними дієприкметниками, через що, попри вже добре відому тенденцію не вживати активні дієприкметники у невластивій їм функції, тексти, зокрема рекламні, ще й досі рясніють перлами на взірець «охолоджуючий напій» (замість *охолоджувальний*), «керуючий пристрій» (замість *керівний*), «фіксуючий засіб» (замість *фіксувальний*) тощо. З іншого боку, з мови примусово вилучено віддієслівні прикметники із суфіксом ***-івн-***. «Вижили» (*принаймні у словниках*) лише кілька: *рятівний, панівний, руйнівний, гальмівний, будівний, чарівний, фільтрівний, засівний, гартівний, нищівний*.
>
> На сьогодні вже майже зовсім втрачено відчуття семантичної відмінности між спільнокореневими прикметниками, що означають призначення до певної функції/дії (*рятувальний* човен, *фільтрувальний* пристрій, *гартувальний* розчин, *коксувальна* піч) та здатність/властивість виконувати дію (*рятівна* соломинка, *фільтрівний* ґрунт, *йонізівне* проміння, *гартівне* середовище). Прикметники, що вказують на призначення до дії, переважно творяться додаванням до дієслівної основи суфікса ***-льн-*** (*чита-льн-ий, роздава-льн-ий, фільтрува-льн-ий, гостри-льн-ий, дої-льн-ий*), а прикметники, що означають здатність предмета виконувати дію — передусім додаванням суфікса ***-н-*** до найпродуктивнішої в науковій мові дієслівної твірної основи із суфіксом ***-ува-*** (*гарт-ува-ти — гарт-івн-ий, руйн-ува-ти — руйн-івн-ий.* У цих дієсловах ***-ів-*** — це трансформ суфікса основи ***-ува-***, коли до нього приєднують суфікс ***-н-***, пор. також пан-ува-ти — пан-ів+н(ий), кер-ува-ти — кер-ів+н(ий) (від суфікса ***-ува-*** відтинаємо кінцевий голосний ***а***, а звук ***у*** чергуємо з ***і***: *гарт-ув(а)-ти — гартівний*).
>
> Отже, попри невелику поширеність обговорюваних прикметників, особливо віддієслівних прикметників з фіналями ***-овн***(ий), ***-івн***(ий) у загальнолітературній мові, наукова мова їх гостро потребує, а тому й активно продукує, бо носії фахової мови прагнуть стислих та точних засобів висловлювання абстрактних та вузькофахових видових процесових понять. Науковці творять термінні прикметники інтуїтивно, силою свого мовного чуття. Нові віддієслівні прикметники з малопродуктивними в загальнолітературній мові суфіксами ***-івн-, -овн-, -енн-, -анн-*** дедалі частіше з’являються у фахових словниках та науковій літературі. Досі на заваді їхньому дальшому поширюванню стоять редактори старого гарту, але ми певні, що здоровий глузд переможе. Немає потреби вживати *невимовні* кострубаті покручі, якщо в мові існують цілком *легковимовні*, зрозумілі й семантично прозорі слова.

Отже, найліпше казати ***доглядальна*** косметика, бо вона саме для цього призначена. Звісно, купуючи *доглядальну косметику* ми сподіваємось, що вона також *доглядівна косметика*, тобто, що вона таки може/здатна допомогти у догляді за, скажімо, шкірою.

Comment: А в чому різниця між -івн- й -овн-? Я так розумію, семантичної різниці нема, просто -овн-, коли наголос падає на суфікс, й -івн- в інших випадках? Чому тоді "доглядівна", якщо _довглядо́вний_ уже трапляється в словниках, книгах й Інтернеті (хоча й нечасто), а "доглядівний" (імовірно, наголос _доглядівни́й_?) я не бачу в гуглі жодного разу?

Comment: @Sasha *-овн-* - це пасивна здатність, а *-івн-* - це здатність виконувати дію. *Доглядовний* - це той, що його можна доглядати.

Comment: В пригоді. 

Це не активна, це пасивна здатність. 

Я вважала "доглядальну" штучним конструктом, але, виявляється, можна вигадати й дещо суворіше.

Comment: @OlenaLisovs'ka пригоди це у Тома Сойєра, а це може стати в нагоді;) Про яку здатьність ви говорите? Коли йдеться про призначення, то ***-льн-*** це те, що треба, наприклад, *читальна зала* - зала призначена для читання.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D1%96+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0&oq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D1%96+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60.3758j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8, прошу

Answer (score 1):

***Доглядо́вий*** бачу в ["Словниках України on-line"](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/). Однак у "Великому тлумачному словнику сучасної української мови" його значення подається як ["призначений для митного, прикордонного і т. ін. догляду, перевірки"](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9), тобто начебто не підходить. Хоча [в "ГРАК"](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=wordrow&%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2([%5E%D1%96]|%D1%96.).*) також трапляється в контексті догляду за дітьми й догляду за рослинами, а [в "Гугл-Книгах"](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9) (а саме [в книзі "Іскра радості: ілюстрований майстер-клас з організації простору та прибирання" Марі Кондо](//google.com/books?id=xTxgDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT202&dq=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9)) бачимо й у потрібному значенні: "Пам'ятайте, що доглядові засоби і декоративну косметику треба зберігати окремо". А ще є в "Англійсько-українсько-англійському словнику наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки)" Кочерги й Мейнаровича з доволі широким спектром значень: "maintenance, maintaining, attendance, upkeep" ([анг.-укр.](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&dicts=4&highlight=on&filter_lines=on), [укр.-анг.](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&dicts=5&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)). Просто в "Гуглі" для, наприклад, "доглядовий крем" бачу [55 траплянь](//google.com/search?q="%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC").

***Догляда́льний*** серед словників бачу лише [в "Російсько-українському словнику складної лексики" Караванського](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=30&highlight=on), і значення там не зовсім те — імовірно, мається на увазі догляд за дітьми. [У "ГРАК"](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=wordrow&word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD(%D0%B8[%5E%D0%BA%D1%86]|[%5E%D0%B8]).*) наразі єдине трапляння — ["Криве дзеркало украiнськоi мови" Нечуй-Левицького](//uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0i%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BEi_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) — і там те саме значення ("доглядальні школи"). Але просто в "Гуглі" в потрібному значенні трапляється, хоча й нечасто, наприклад, для "доглядовий крем" бачу [12 траплянь](//google.com/search?q="%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC").

Обидва слова доволі рідковживані (більшість словників їх не мають). Мені, якщо чесно, обидва варіанти око ріжуть (я надав би перевану "…для догляду"). Але формально, здається, ніщо не забороняє їх уживати (і їх де-факто вживають). *Доглядовий* трішки популярніше (і в словниках, і в ужитку загалом, і в ужитку в потрібному значенні).

Щодо контексту медичного чи косметичного, то, якщо вже вживати, я не бачу причин обмежувати вжиток чи вважати, що слово може стосуватися лише одного з контекстів (тобто я б тоді розумів *доглядовий*/*доглядальний* як "той, що стосується догляду (будь-якого: медичного, косметичного, іншого)").